# Java how to convert UK into java.util.Date

Tags: java

I'm retrieving a date in a HTML form, and I need to convert the string date into a java.util.Date so that it can be inserted into a database.

I've tried the following, but it always gives me a date in May 2008.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date myDate = formatter.parse("27-11-2015");
```

Comment: Is this a serious question?

Comment: Year 27, month 11, day 2015? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Sorry, it's my mistake, the date format is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

```
String string = "2015-11-27";
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date date = format.parse(string);
System.out.println(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

This was user error, my code should have been:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
Date myDate = formatter.parse("27-11-2015");
```